# Render database values in template django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created an app called 'student.' From this I have to access database values on templates. I have done the changes and applied migrations but it shows

> No changes detected in app 'student'

when I visit the

```
http://localhost:8000/student/
```

I only get the text from the HTML file but am not getting database values.
I want output like this:

> the student here,
>   name,
>   department,
>   class,

on the web page.

1. `models.py` file:

   ```
   python
   from django.db import models
   class Student(models.Model):
       roll_no = models.TextField()
       name = models.TextField(max_length = 40)
       stud_class = models.TextField()
       department = models.TextField()
   ```
2. `views.py` file:

   ```
   python
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from .models import Student

   def student_show(request):
       student = Student.objects.all() #order_by('roll_no')
       return render(request,'student/student1_show.html', {'student':student})
   ```

Comment: please show us the template.

Comment: Why would your URL be "phpmyadmin"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman URL edited

Comment: @hansTheFranz  template:'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Student_Show</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Students Here</h1>
<div>
<ul>
{% for stud in student %}
<li>
<h2>Name {{ stud.name }}</h2>
<p> department {{ stud.department}}</p>
<p> class {{ stud.standard}}</p>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
'